# Multiple DATEADD functions in one query - TSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to make multiple edits on a random date to leave a full random datetime within a range of dates (3 months back, 3 months forward) but setting the Hours/Minutes/Seconds/Milliseconds to 0.

I'm doing this so I can then add a random amount of time to create activity start and end times that will always fit within office working hours. The script below sets a variable for the start time of the activity, then carries out 5 separate edits to this variable to zero the time element.

Is there an easier way to carry out multiple DATEADD edits, it seems clunky!

```
DECLARE @STARTTIME DATETIME
DECLARE @ENDTIME DATETIME

SET @STARTTIME = (SELECT DATEADD(DAY,ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID()) % 180), (select dateadd(dd, -90, getdate()) )))

SET @STARTTIME = (SELECT DATEADD(HH, - (SELECT DATEPART(HH,@STARTTIME)),@STARTTIME))
SET @STARTTIME = (SELECT DATEADD(MI, - (SELECT DATEPART(MI,@STARTTIME)),@STARTTIME))
SET @STARTTIME = (SELECT DATEADD(SS, - (SELECT DATEPART(SS,@STARTTIME)),@STARTTIME))
SET @STARTTIME = (SELECT DATEADD(MS, - (SELECT DATEPART(MS,@STARTTIME)),@STARTTIME))
SET @STARTTIME = (SELECT DATEADD(hh,(SELECT FLOOR(RAND()*(15-08)+08)), @STARTTIME))
SET @ENDTIME = (SELECT DATEADD(hh,(SELECT FLOOR(RAND()*(3-1)+1)), @STARTTIME))

SELECT
@STARTTIME AS 'STARTTIME',
@ENDTIME AS 'ENDTIME'

Results
STARTIME 2017-04-02 13:00:00.000
ENDTIME  2017-04-02 15:00:00.000
```

Comment: N.B. in a SET statement you don't strictly need the SELECTs before each call to a function (e.g DATEADD). Will make the code a touch more readable. I don't know about clunky, at least your code is fairly clear. You _could_ chain all the DateAdd statements onto each other one line but that would just create a horrible unreadable mess.

Comment: Much appreciated, and thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is not a need to use `newid()` in T-SQL code.  It is only needed within a query to generate multiple random numbers.

So:

```
set @starttime = cast(datedd(day, floor(rand() * 180 - 90), getdate()) as date);

set @starttime = dateadd(hour, floor(rand()*(15-08)+08), @starttime);
set @enddtime = dateadd(hour, floor(rand()*(3-1)+1), @starttime);
```

Notes:

- This uses `cast(. . . as date)` to remove the time component of the date.
- There is no need to have nested `select` statements.
- For T-SQL code, you can use `rand()`, rather than the `newid()` work-around (that is needed within a single query to generate multiple random values).
- Don't use date part abbreviations such as "hh".  Just spell out the date part.  The code is much easier to write and maintain.

Comment: This is great advice, thank you. Your solution was also a lot easier than I was making it! I did edit the 'CAST line slightly for it to work: set @starttime = cast(dateadd(day, floor(rand() * 180 - 90), getdate()) as date);

Answer (score 2):

You convert it to a Date data type would set the time part to 00:00:000

```
DECLARE @STARTTIME DATETIME
DECLARE @ENDTIME DATETIME

SET @STARTTIME = cast((SELECT DATEADD(DAY,ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID()) % 180), (select dateadd(dd, -90, getdate()) ))) as date)

SET @STARTTIME = (SELECT DATEADD(hh,(SELECT FLOOR(RAND()*(15-08)+08)), @STARTTIME))
SET @ENDTIME = (SELECT DATEADD(hh,(SELECT FLOOR(RAND()*(3-1)+1)), @STARTTIME))

SELECT
@STARTTIME AS 'STARTTIME',
@ENDTIME AS 'ENDTIME'
```

Comment: Thank you for this, it did exactly as asked and solved my problem. Apologies that I've given the solution to the post by Gordon, it was a more complete answer for future users. Thanks again!